# Hello All - Java Script Quiz

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write a simple quiz.

[here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajuLqv4h/)

I want to create an array of questions, pass it into a loop and print the final answer through a variable which will compute 20 marks for every right answer.

```
function Myfunction() {

    var y = ["q0",
    "q1",
    "q2",
    "q3",
    "q4"];

    for (i = 0; i <= y.length; i++) {
        var x = document.getElementById(y[i]).value("correct");
        var score = x * 20;
        alert("Your score is" & "score");
        break;
    }
}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Welcome to your Web Quiz</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quiz.css" />
    <form>
        <h1>
            Quiz about corporate crap
        </h1>
        <div class="questions">
            What's the difference between a boss and a manager?
            <ul><input type="radio" id="q0" value="correct">Boss is a boss</ul>
            <ul><input type="radio" id="q0" value="False">Manager is a manager</ul>
            <ul><input type="radio" id="q0" value="False">Both are blah </ul>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="questions">
            What's the right thing to do?
            <br>
            <ul><input type="radio" id="q1" value="correct">Do what the boss says </ul>
            <ul><input type="radio" id="q1" value="False">Do what the bosses boss says</ul>
            <ul><input type="radio" id="q1" value="False">Dont give a fuck do what you want to do</ul>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="questions">
            Listen to your heart is that good advice?
            <ul><input type="radio" id="q2" value="correct">Listen to it, do not execute</ul>
            <ul><input type="radio" id="q2" value="False">Shove it up your a#$$</ul>
            <ul><input type="radio" id="q2" value="False"> Shove it up some one elses a$#$</ul>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="questions">
            <br>
            Who is a client?
            <ul><input type="radio" id="q3" value="correct">Someone whose astrological charts are right</ul>
            <ul><input type="radio" id="q3" value="False">Who gets payed to screw around</ul>
            <ul><input type="radio" id="q3" value="False">Someone who is arrogant about being stupid and proud about it </ul>

        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="I am done" align="center" onsubmit= "Myfunction()">
    </form>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd start by putting your actual html **not** in the head, and into the **body**. oh, and rtfm too :)

Answer (score 2):

a button does not have an `onsubmit` event, a form does, however.

Try changing

```
<input type="button" value="I am done" align="center" onsubmit= "Myfunction()">
```

to

```
<input type="button" value="I am done" align="center" onclick="Myfunction()"/>
```

Or you could change

```
<form>
```

to

```
<form onsubmit="Myfunction()">
```

Which is better as it catches the submit event if the enter key is hit for example

Comment: As you suggests, a form does have an `onsubmit` event. It's better to use that event, since you can submit a form without clicking the submit button.

Comment: Hello All, I had tried doing this both previously, it does not work. JS fiddle hint says the Jscript code is perfectly valid as well. Is there any thing else I can do, Is there a flaw in the logic? Kindly help me out, as I said am not trying to get the job done from some one, actually this is possibly the first set of code I have written and do not have much help around here.

Comment: Well, probably whats happening is the form submits before the js has a chance to run. try adding `return false;` at the end of your function